# Problem with Krew “Error: flags cannot be placed before plugin name”

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I have a local minikube cluster (version: v1.21.0) with kubectl:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.7", GitCommit:"132a687512d7fb058d0f5890f07d4121b3f0a2e2", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-05-12T12:40:09Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.12", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.7", GitCommit:"132a687512d7fb058d0f5890f07d4121b3f0a2e2", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-05-12T12:32:49Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.12", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

I installed krew according to the documentation: https://krew.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user-guide/setup/install/

Then, when I try to execute any command this is the result:

> Error: flags cannot be placed before plugin name: --cluster

For example:

```
minikube kubectl krew version
Error: flags cannot be placed before plugin name: --cluster
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are running the **minikube** in command before the **kubectl**

```
minikube kubectl krew version
```

You can set and use the context of K8s using this command

```
kubectl config use-context CONTEXT_NAME
```

Using the **kubectl** only you can access the **Krew** and install the plugins

```
kubectl krew install access-matrix
```

example

```
kubectl access-matrix
```

Read more at : https://krew.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user-guide/quickstart/

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/884

Comment: Thanks! I think that was the problem. I solved it by installing kubectl directly on the host

Comment: You ask why -- but the minikube instructions advise you to do so (I believe to ensure version sync). https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/kubectl/# . If you search your system, you will likely find the kubectl binary that minikube placed there too, like such: `/var/lib/minikube/binaries/v1.23.1/kubectl`

Comment: And if you want to live life on the edge, you can probably copy minikube's kubectl to the regular location like such: `cp $(find /var/lib/minikube/binaries/ -name kubectl -print -quit) /usr/local/bin/`

Comment: There is an odd satisfaction to finding the quick and dirty answer... in a comment i left over a year ago :-)

Answer (score 0):

I just removed my alias suggested by the documentation from minikube `alias kubectl="minikube kubectl --"` and replace installing kubectl directly on my OS (Ubuntu 20.04):

```
curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/release/$(curl -L -s https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl"\n
sudo install -o root -g root -m 0755 kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
kubectl version --client
```

Refer:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-linux/